# Powershell script to send keys alt tab

Tags: powershell, sendkeys, alt-key

I have an .exe file that I'm running using `Start-Process`. Once my application opens, I want to send first tab key and then do <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>.
I'm using following commands, but so far only my application is launched.

```
Start-Process -FilePath $Exe -WorkingDirectory $Path 
Start-Sleep 10
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait(“{TAB}”)
Start-Sleep 2
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait(“%{TAB}”)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath $Exe -WorkingDirectory $Path 
$wsh = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell 
$wsh.AppActivate("Window title of $exe")
Start-Sleep 10 
$wsh.SendKeys("{TAB}") 
Start-Sleep 2 
$wsh.Sendkeys("%{TAB}")
```

You need to activate the exe file's window with its window title. Also prefer Wscript.Shell to send keys. Replace "Window title of $exe" with its window title.